# Can AppleScript detect if Netflix or YouTube is playing?

Tags: macos, applescript, safari, automation

I have a script that detects if QuickTime Player is [playing something in general](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427391/how-to-detect-with-applescript-if-something-is-playing) but I also need a way to detect if Safari is playing something specific like Netflix or YouTube but if it could detect any playing activity at all then that would be better.

```
on mySay(p, myMessage)
    if application "QuickTime Player" is running then
        tell application "QuickTime Player" to set isQTplaying to ¬
            ((documents whose playing is true) is not {}) as boolean
    else
        set isQTplaying to false
    end if
        
    if isQTplaying then
        return
    else
        set myVolumeBefore to output volume of (get volume settings)
        set volume output volume p
        say myMessage
        set volume output volume myVolumeBefore
    end if
end mySay
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect with AppleScript if something is playing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427391/how-to-detect-with-applescript-if-something-is-playing)

Comment: Actually that is my post but it didn't have a solution for Safari which is why I reposted it specific to that.

Comment: You probably could get the URLs of the currently opened tabs from Safari.

Comment: But that would not tell me if it was playing right?

Comment: What version of **macOS** and **Safari**  are you running?

Comment: We may want to close [this or that](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/427391/how-to-detect-with-applescript-if-something-is-playing) once we have answers or merge them. Is “playing“ specifically for video or do you want any audio so you can duck other output?

Comment: @user3439894 11.5.2 and 14.1.2

Comment: @bmike I really would like it for ANY audio. Maybe there is a better way instead of detecting on the app level? Maybe detecting on the audio core layer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way you can test if video is playing in **Safari**.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
if (do shell script "pmset -g | grep -m 1 'displaysleep'") ¬
    contains "display sleep prevented by Safari" then
    
    --  # Video is playing.
    --  # Do something when video is playing.
    
else
    
    --  # Video is not playing.
    --  # Do something else when video is not playing.
    
end if
```

**Notes:**

Tested in **macOS Catalina**.

The `contains "display sleep prevented by Safari"` clause could actually only contain `contains "Safari"` and it would work. If you have, e.g. **Firefox** playing video you would use just `firefox` in that clause, and just `Google Chrome` for **Google Chrome**.

<sub>Generally speaking parentheses around the `do shell script` *command* are not necessary, except in this use case to allow for the use of the line continuation character, `¬`, to have been placed where it is.</sub>

Comment: Fascinating and ++! I wonder if other browser commands can trigger the “prevent sleep state” for reasons other than a video player, but this is unexpectedly awesome.

Comment: @bmike, RE: "I wonder if other browser commands can trigger the “prevent sleep state” for reasons other than a video player" --  Not sure on that, however, if in a normal window, tested in **macOS Catalina**, `tell application "System Events" to if exists (buttons of group 2 of toolbar 1 of window 1 of application process "Safari" whose description contains "Mute This Tab") then return true` works for anything producing an audio signal in **Safari**.

Comment: Thank you kindly for entertaining a follow on question and nailing it. Much obliged

Comment: @bmike, For an audio only stream in **Firefox** and **Google Chrome** you can use e.g., `if (do shell script "pmset -g | grep -m 1 'sleep'") contains "firefox" then` or for **Google Chrome**  `contains "Google Chrome"`, however for **Safari** it is not definitive and only reports `sleep prevented by coreaudiod` when using `'sleep'`, and why I gave you a **UI Scripting** solution in the previous comment.

Comment: @user3439894 I'm going to use what you posted even though I wasn't able to get it to work in FireFox or Safari. It did however work in Brave Browser which is mostly what I would be using. I will just test for "display sleep prevented" so I don't have to test for individual apps. It worked for QTP and VLC too.

Comment: @Steve Torrence, What I posted is after all, just an _example_, and you can use `pmset -g` in **Terminal** to see how it changes when the various _browsers/applications_ change its _option_ when _video_ and or just _audio_ is playing/not playing and see what is best to test against. In you question you mentioned **Netflix**, **YouTube** and **Safari** and never mention other _browsers/applications_ as the target for the answer. Between what I included in my answer and comments to bmike, I'm sure the _code_ can be modified to accommodate.

Comment: @user3439894 to check for audio in general I changed it to: if (do shell script "pmset -g | grep -m 1 'sleep'") ¬ does not contain "coreaudiod" then end if For some reason it's not working. – 
I think the reason might be because coreaudiod is listed even when nothing is playing. So it's not a reliable check.

Comment: @Steve Torrence, Please understand that what is presented in the answer is an _example_ and is not meant to be a catch all solution for everything as the question was focused on **Netflix**, **YouTube** and **Safari** as you did after all say "I also need a way to detect if Safari is playing something specific like Netflix or YouTube" and the main point of my answer does that. If you want a catch all then you need to do the research and devise a method that fulfills all your needs as **Ask Different** is not a code writing service. I believe **Netflix**, and **YouTube** only plays videos.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post the final solution I ended up using. Based off @user3439894 example.

```
on mySay(p, myMessage)
    if (do shell script "pmset -g | grep -m 1 'displaysleep'") ¬
        does not contain "prevented" then
        set myVolumeBefore to output volume of (get volume settings)
        set volume output volume p
        say myMessage
        set volume output volume myVolumeBefore
    end if
end mySay
```